# How to plot a 3-D plot with 3 input variables in R?

Tags: r, plot

I am writing a log-likelihood surface for the function:

ln[Pr(Y_A=186,Y_B=38,Y_{AB}=13,Y_O=284)]
= ln(G+186*ln(A^2+2*A*O)+38*ln(B^2+2*B*O)+13*ln(2*A*B)+284*ln(O^2))

constraint by A+B+O=1

```
A = seq(0.0001, .9999,length=50)
B = A
O = A
G = 1.129675e-06   
f = function(A,B,O){F = ifelse(A+B+O==1,
                    G+186*log(A*A+2*A*O)+38*log(B*B+2*B*O)+13*log(2*A*B)+284*log(O*O), O)}
Z <- outer(A, B, O, f)
png()
persp(A,B,Z, theta=60, phi=30 )
dev.off()
```

The error told me that there isn't object "O".

```
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir)
```

What I mean to do is to input A, B and O under the constraint that A+B+O=1, and then to plot the log-likelihood surface letting A:x-axis, B:y-axis, log-likelihood:z-axis.

I **cannot** get rid of "O" cause the instruction commands that the parameter of the function should be a 3-dimensional vector: A,B,O.

So what should I do to improve my current code?
If I need to change a function, can anyone suggest a function to use?
(I think maybe I can use barycentric coordinates but I consider it as the last thing I want to do.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `outer` function does not work the way you try to use it. `outer` takes two numeric arguments `X` and `Y` and a function argument `FUN` to which the first two arguments are applied. See `?outer`. So it is not that there is no object `O` at all. Rather the error message in

```
Z <- outer(A, B, O, f)
#Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
#   object 'O' of mode 'function' was not found
```

means that the *function* `O` was not found. Indeed there is no such function.

There are also some problems with your `f` definition. First, it does not return anything. It saves a result as `F` but never returns it. Secondly, even if it returned `F`, the output would not always satisfy your constraint. When your constraint is not met, it simply outputs the value of `O`. Lastly, the comparison `A+B+O==1` is a bad test as it may not evaluate to `TRUE` even if you'd expect it to due to floating point precision (try to run `3 - 2.9 == 0.1`). The grid based evaluation makes things worse. Probably, you should be testing `abs(A+B+O-1) < epsilon` instead if you insist have three arguments for `f`.  I.e. I would have expect something like:

```
f <- function(A, B, O){
  G <- 1.129675e-06
  epsilon <- 1e-3
  ifelse(abs(A+B+O-1) < epsilon,
         G+186*log(A*A+2*A*O)+38*log(B*B+2*B*O)+13*log(2*A*B)+284*log(O*O),
         NA)
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
dat <- expand.grid(A = A, B = B, O = O) # All combinations of A, B, O
dat$Z <- f(dat$A, dat$B, dat$O) # Apply function
head(dat)
#           A     B     O  Z
#1 0.00010000 1e-04 1e-04 NA
#2 0.02050408 1e-04 1e-04 NA
#3 0.04090816 1e-04 1e-04 NA
#4 0.06131224 1e-04 1e-04 NA
#5 0.08171633 1e-04 1e-04 NA
#6 0.10212041 1e-04 1e-04 NA
```

But I do not see how you readily plot Z as a function of A and B from this. You'd need to subset to remove NAs and it seems very wasteful computationally. Also note `any(dat$A + dat$B + dat$O == 1)` returns `FALSE`, so your original constraint test indeed always fails on this grid.

With that said, why do you not determine `O` given `A` and `B` using your constraint within the function?

```
A <- seq(0.0001, .9999,length=50)
B <- A

f <- function(A, B){
  G <- 1.129675e-06
  O <- 1 - A - B
  out <-  G+186*log(A*A+2*A*O)+38*log(B*B+2*B*O)+13*log(2*A*B)+284*log(O*O)
  return(out)
}

Z <- outer(A, B, f)
#Warning messages:
#1: In log(A * A + 2 * A * O) : NaNs produced
#2: In log(B * B + 2 * B * O) : NaNs produced

Z[is.infinite(Z)] <- NA

persp(A, B, Z, theta=60, phi=30, zlim = range(Z, na.rm = TRUE))
```

[image]

Does that look right? That is how `persp` and `outer` is intended to be used at least.

Of course, you can modify `f` so the warning messages are avoided. Just keep in mind that `f` needs to be vectorized.